# Database not copied in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android

I write the code of database copy in /data/data path. but it gives this error

```
sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.mycom.package/databases/My Bookback", &handle, 2, NULL) failed 

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open  database file and copy.  05-23 13:19:46.746: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9120): 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Details: ,
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dest directory could not be present on filesystem.

I resolved in this way.

```
File fDir = new File(DB_PATH);
if (!fDir.exists()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Create directory " + fDir.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + fDir.mkdir());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Copying the database from assets is generally a bad idea. DB should be created/accessed through the SQLiteOpenHelper class. You can use the onCreate method to populate the DB content.

Comment: why its a bad idea, please explain.